# Efficiently converting 2D array to an object erasing duplicates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

For example if one has the following 2D array (arranged to be [[key, value], [key, value]]):

```
var input_array = [
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "things"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "stuff"], 
  ["one", "something"], 
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "more stuff"]
]
```

What is a minimal and efficient way using what ES5/6 has to offer (as oppose to for loops with counters) to create an output object with array values that get rid of the duplicate pairs and sort the array values in *alphabetical order*:

```
var output_obj = {
  "one": ["something", "stuff"],
  "two": ["more things", "things"],
  "three": ["more stuff", "stuff"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be as concise as a single line reduce using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), adding elements to a [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) to handle duplicates, and then iterating the resulting [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to convert the `Set`s to arrays using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) while also sorting them.

```js
const input = [["one", "stuff"], ["two", "things"], ["two", "more things"], ["three", "stuff"], ["one", "something"], ["one", "stuff"], ["two", "more things"], ["three", "more stuff"]];

const
  output = input.reduce((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k] ??= new Set()).add(v), a), {});
Object.keys(output).forEach(k => output[k] = [...output[k]].sort());

console.log(output)
```

or if you need to avoid logical nullish assignment for [compatibility...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment#browser_compatibility)

```js
const input = [["one", "stuff"], ["two", "things"], ["two", "more things"], ["three", "stuff"], ["one", "something"], ["one", "stuff"], ["two", "more things"], ["three", "more stuff"]];

const
  output = input.reduce((a, [k, v]) => ((a[k] = a[k] || new Set()).add(v), a), {});
Object.keys(output).forEach(k => output[k] = [...output[k]].sort());

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can create the map of string to list (array) first and then sort them.

```js
const fn = (arr) => {
    const results = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr[0]] = acc[curr[0]] || [];
    if (!acc[curr[0]].includes(curr[1])) {
        acc[curr[0]].push(curr[1]);
    }
    return acc;
    }, {});
  Object.values(results).forEach(vals => vals.sort());
  return results;
}

console.log(fn([
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "things"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "stuff"], 
  ["one", "something"], 
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "more stuff"]
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

One efficient ES6 way of eliminating duplicates is by using `Set`.

```js
const input_array = [
  ['one', 'stuff'],
  ['two', 'things'],
  ['two', 'more things'],
  ['three', 'stuff'],
  ['one', 'something'],
  ['one', 'stuff'],
  ['two', 'more things'],
  ['three', 'more stuff']
];

// create object containing sets
const output_obj = input_array
  .reduce((sets, [key, val]) => {
    sets[key] = sets[key] || new Set();
    sets[key].add(val);
    return sets;
  }, {});

// convert each set to a sorted array
Object.entries(output_obj)
  .forEach(([key, set]) => {
    output_obj[key] = [...set].sort();
  });

console.log('output_obj:', output_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order Objects, but...

```js
const input_array = [
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "things"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "stuff"], 
  ["one", "something"], 
  ["one", "stuff"], 
  ["two", "more things"], 
  ["three", "more stuff"]
];
let obj = {}, p, v;
for(let a of input_array){
  p = a[0]; v = a[1];
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)){
    if(obj[p].indexOf(v) === -1)obj[p].push(v);
  }
  else{
    obj[p] = [v];
  }
}
for(let i in obj){
  obj[i].sort();
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment there is no arrays as values, just a single value

Comment: Except they aren't unnecessary array values

Comment: Have a look at your output compared to the example output from the question. You are wiping out values that have different strings as long as one of the words is the same (which isn't the goal). Your updated edit at this point in time still doesn't accomplish that unfortunately.